# JQUERY is not loading properly or is it my code that is wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery methods for ajax to create a dropdown menu.
Using this jQuery code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<SCRIPT>
$("select[name='carid']").on("change", function() {
  $.post(
    "execute.php",
    { carid: $("#carid").val() },
    function(data) {
      $("available").append(data);
    }
  );
});
</SCRIPT>
```

execute.php :

```
<?php
$carid = $_POST['carid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT mID, mName FROM Model WHERE cID = '$carid' ");
$select = "<select>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $mID = $row['mID'];
    $mName = $row['mName'];
    $select+= "<option value='".$mID."'>" .$mName. "</option>";
}
$select += "</select>"
echo $select;

?>
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error on loading in console `event.returnValue` is deprecated. Please use the standard `event.preventDefault()` instead. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what you are getting is not an error it is a warning

Comment: add your script within a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) like `$(function(){ //your script })`.... the script looks fine... whether there is any error in your console

Comment: What is `$("available")`?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: It is a <div> tag within a form

Comment: @user3104737 what is `available`? `<div>`'s `id` or `class` or what?

Comment: yes its a <div id="available">  </div>

Comment: @user3104737 please check my answer below, then.. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here I think:

```
$("available").append(data);
```

What is `available` here? It won't append `data` any where.

Since you haven't shown us your html so assuming that it may be an element with id or class set to `available` so  it should be `$(".available").append(data);` or `$("available").append(data);` depending upon the element to which you want to append.

**UPDATE**

since you specified that it's a `<div id="available">` so try `$("#available").append(data);` instead of `$("available").append(data);`

Here is the complete `script`

```
<script>
$("select[name='carid']").on("change", function() {
  $.post(
    "execute.php",
    { carid: $("#carid").val() },
    function(data) {
      console.log(data); // just for testing
      $("#available").append(data);
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

If that doesn't work either, check your console and post the output here.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line and try again

```
 $select += "</select>";
```

and if $("available").append(data); in this line available is class than use .available and if it an id than use #available

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work :S

Answer (score 0):

See here

[event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045162/event-returnvalue-is-deprecated-please-use-the-standard-event-preventdefault)

This is just a warning and can be safely ignored for the time being. It has been changed in jQuery 1.11