# jQuery modal is not working in latest version and event.returnvalue is deprecated error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript function for some sort of validation,

**EDIT**

I made an edit to below function with exact piece of code that works in firefox but not in chrome and gives below errors,

```
function check_time () {
    var start_time = $("#start_time select").val();
    var end_time = $("#end_time select").val();

    var stt = new Date("November 24, 2013 " + start_time);
    stt = stt.getTime();
    var endt = new Date("November 24, 2013 " + end_time);
    endt = endt.getTime();

    if(stt > endt || stt == endt) {
        $('#popup_box').show();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#popup_box').hide();
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine in Firefox, but in Chrome, I got an error, and my script doesn't execute:

```
event.returnvalue is deprecated. please use the standard event.preventdefault() instead
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045162/event-returnvalue-is-deprecated-please-use-the-standard-event-preventdefault) link,

I changed my jQuery version to 1.10.2 and also tried with 2.0.3.

Still won't work in chrome, and by using this, jQuery modal fails to load except of screen size overlay, and console shows this error..

> c.browser is undefined // line 396 in my jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js version

my jQuery and css files are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>public/css/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" type="text/css"   />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>public/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>public/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Please guide me to resolve these two issues below,

1. if i use 1.7.1 that I was previously using, modal works fine, but I got chrome error.
2. if i use 1.10.2 or latest version of jQuery to get rid of Chrome error, I face both "chrome" error and "modal" error

Comment: `check()` can be simplified to just `return condition;` or `return !!condition;` if it has to be coerced into a boolean.

Comment: Have you tried jquery 1.9 and jquery ui 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

The issue related to e.returnValue is a warning not an error.

The main problem is jQuery ui 1.8.* which uses features that were removed in jQuery 1.9.

Use jQuery [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) for backward compatibility if you can't upgrade jQuery ui

Comment: fine, using migration plugin, can i fix the chrome error too?

Comment: found TypeError: c.curCSS is not a function on line 61 in jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js after using migration plugin,

Comment: i can ignore such type of warning only if doesn't harm my code in one browser. which is not.