# avoid "submit" when user hits enter in form with only one input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using (all right, just starting to learn) bootstrap and javascript and jQuery. I have a rather extensive experience in other programming languages, and I like understanding what happens.

so I have a dialog box containing just one input box, and I do not want a POST action to be fired when the user hits enter. I am using a dirty trick according to me, and I'm wondering how to do this more neatly.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="well">
    <input id="empty" name="empty" type="hidden"/></form>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr><td width="30%">accession#.plant#</td>
        <td><input id="addendum" name="keyword" type="text"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

the unused "empty" form, it's the dirty trick that works for me on firefox 27.0.1

I have tried disabling the enter key completely, as suggested by answers to similar questions, but it has a non desirable side effect according to me: when entering data in a input element, the browser will give hints. disabling the enter key makes difficult selecting among them.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235672/716691

Comment: I agree on "similar", not on "duplicate".

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without seeing the JavaScript, but you should be able to call `preventDefault` on the event object in JavaScript. This keeps the form from submitting, but shouldn't interfere with the type ahead behavior in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Give the form an id and then put the id in the keypress function... It should work.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#[formid]').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventdefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: tried this, does not work. form is POST-ed on pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it will prevent form submission if no field have been inputed.

```
$( ".well" ).on( "submit", function() { 
  var has_empty = false;
  $(this).find( 'input' ).each(function () {
    if ( ! $(this).val() ) { has_empty = true; return false; }
  });
if ( has_empty ) { return false; }
});
```

EDIT: Biding it to the enter listener:

```
$(".well").bind("keyup keypress", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    e.preventDefault();
    var has_empty = false;
    $(this).find( 'input' ).each(function () {
      if ( ! $(this).val() ) { has_empty = true; return false; }
    });
    if ( has_empty ) { return false; }
  }
});
```

Comment: but this is a huge amount of code! my dirty trick sort of looks better, isn't it?

Comment: If it works, why not :) But I'm not sure if your solutions works for every browsers. If you want something strong enough, and which works everywhere, I suggest to go with my solution.
Between, it is indeed long, but this is the client which executes it, and the process time is ridiculously low, it should not be a problem ;)