# Disable Enter Keypress on Form Submit & Change it into a tab instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Disable Enter Keypress on Form Submit & Change it into a tab instead

How do I disable the key "enter keydown" on form submit button, because in a form, when I press "enter", it will submit my form.

I want my enter to become "tab" instead, so when I press enter e.g at

input text id="text_1", i want maybe change it focus to "small_1" (another textfield) , then if I press enter again at small_1, I want change it focus to big_1

and so on

How do I achieve this, I tried jquery autotab but it doesn't work like what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to watch for the enter key being pressed (using jQuery):

```
$("#text_1").bind("keyup keypress", function(event){
    var code = event.keyCode || event.which; 
      if (code == 13)  {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#small_1").offset().top
          }, 2000);
          return false;
      }
});

$("#small_1").bind("keyup keypress", function(event){
      var code = event.keyCode || event.which; 
      if (code == 13)  {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#big_1").offset().top
          }, 2000);
          return false;
      }
});
```

You could set these up with JavaScript to detect the elements (and generate strings for the ids in a for loop) so you don't have to do these for each one, and it would also make it easier to add new ones.

Comment: I can't test your solution because when I press enter, it just simply form submit as my submit button is at the top of my page. inside <form> tag

Comment: This should be prevented by the `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem. Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter I'll edit my answer to fix this.

Comment: I got a question, if I press enter at big_1, i wanna focus to small_1 , but I see your answer small_1 then small1.offset top, and enter still not disabled

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, I'll fix it.

Comment: Could you please make a JSFiddle of what you are trying?