# Disable Enter to submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple TextBoxes, Textarea and Buttons.
By pressing the ENTER in any text box submits the form. So i want to disable the pressing enter only in text boxes and to  enable in text-area and buttons. 
i found a solution but they were using higher jquery version which were not working with mine jquery version. 
Below is the code i wrote but its only enables the enter in test area and not in buttons. 
I only have acces to jquery 1.3.1 or just java script. 
Please help me to fix this code.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var element = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    var element1 = e.target;
    alert(element1);
    if (element != 'textarea') {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Here i do not want to completely disable pressing the ENTER. i want to disable it only in textboxes.

Comment: FYI, that's an extremely inefficient way of binding that event. For something like this, it's best to find the common parent of all inputs and assign the event there...

Comment: @acarroz5 the marked question wnats to disable completely. That dosen't solve my problem. its a different question. Please help

Comment: how are you submitting the form? Via an AJAX call or via a php script?

Comment: When textboxes have focus (give them a class) you could do a preventDefault() on the form submission?

Comment: @midda25 via java script. But this forms is submitted by multiple scripts. Diffrent sscript for delete, update. So i want to add a key press event.

Comment: See above comment...does this work for you?

Comment: _"But this forms is submitted by multiple scripts."_ - Can you expand on this please? How is it submitted by multiple scripts?

Comment: There has to be something very special in your question, if you can't apply `e.preventDefault()` to your code. I just can't see the special nature of the question ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery disable form submit on enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter)

Comment: @TrevorNestman Already flagged that, removed it because it's not a true dup

Comment: @acarroz5 why did u removed ur answer. i have not tried it yet.

Comment: @NimbleFungus It was incorrect, I misread your code. Sorry man

Comment: @acarroz5 No Problem. I am thankful at least you tried.

Comment: @War10ck we are passing some values to controller so multiple scripts for submit. Can you please help me with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  $('input[type=text]').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Js Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bikrampahi/f0gxev76/

Comment: Bikram its not stoping the enter not even in Text Boxes. I have a jquery version 1.3.2. can that be the limitation?

Comment: an ALERT inside this code is not getting called when i am putting ENTER in text area.

Comment: I have implemented this way many time. if it is not working with your jquery version then I will check and update my answer in few minute.

Comment: its not even called.

Comment: I added ALERT in the code and its not working. Alert is not poping up up.https://jsfiddle.net/f0gxev76/1/

Comment: @NimbleFungus Your fiddle was missing jQuery and the document ready handler. When I updated those it works: https://jsfiddle.net/f0gxev76/2/

Comment: @War10ck Thanks you that was the issue. Thanks. Its working in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to the form element but only if there are no textareas on the form.

```
onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;"
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uffbost5/1/