# Trying to add some form control when enter is clicked on an HTML field, getting inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have an HTML form that I'm running with Firefox that looks something like this:

```
<form name="transfer" id = "transferForm" action='transfer.php' method='POST'>
<div>
    <input id="itemSelect" name="itemSelect"/>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1"
        onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" style="width:83px" 
        onclick="addItem()"/>
</div>

<div>
    <span id="myForm"></span>
    <button id='save' name = 'save' style="width:205px">Save</button>
    <button id='transfer' name='transfer' style="width:205px"/>Transfer</button>
</div>
</form>
```

A few things to note:
-itemSelect is a dojo/dijit combobox that is initialized elsewhere. 
-The function addItem(), found in the addButton, runs some javascript that creates new elements in the span myForm each time the add button is clicked. These are processed by transfer.php when the save or transfer button is clicked.

Everything works fine, but I want to add some user friendly controls so the form can work without mouse clicking. I want the user to be able to press 'Enter' when in the "quantity" field, and have the form run the addItem() javascript and move focus back to "itemSelect".

This is the javascript I added. First, to disable the default submit on enter  of the form:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e)
        {if(e.keyIdentifier=='U+000A'||e.keyIdentifier=='Enter'||e.keyCode==13)
        {if(e.target.nodeName=='INPUT'&&e.target.type=='text')
        {e.preventDefault();return false;}}},true);
```

Then I add an event listener to "quantity"

```
    document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            //document.getElementById("addButton").click();
            addItem(); //Same results using this or the line above
            document.getElementById("itemSelect").focus(); //move focus back to the combo box
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

At first glance it appears to work, however I get two different glitches.

1. With this code in place, if I press enter to run the addItem() function the line gets added on the form between the span tags, but when I click "save" or "transfer" to submit the lines added this way do not not POST. In transfer.php lines that were already added show up (), but any new line added by clicking enter does not go through. However if I just click the "addButton" to add a line instead of pressing enter then it POST's just fine.
2. When I test adding lines with the keyboard, pressing TAB-ENTER-TAB-ENTER..., it works fine but after on about the 4th cycle the form suddenly submits to transfer.php.

So what could be going wrong with #1, and how does #2 happen?

Comment: Why you are attaching two event listeners `keyup` and `keypress`?

Comment: I never noticed that actually. I'm still learning javascript and not to familiar with the addEventListener function, so these are two separate tasks and I got two separate answers from google. The keydown one came all in one line, I didn't break it down until I posted it here, so I never looked to closely to what was in it.

Comment: Should these by combined in someway? I tried copying the first part and adding it with keyup so the default for both keydown and keyup should be disabled, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Ideally you should add event listeners in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

**Remove inline event handlers from your HTML**
Seperation of concerns

**Know the difference between onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown**
Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

**Prevent form submission on enter**:

```
document.getElementById("transferForm").addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
    e = e || event;
    var txtArea = /textarea/i.test((e.target || e.srcElement).tagName);
    return txtArea || (e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode || 0) !== 13;
})
```

**Call `addItem` on quantity input enter**

```
document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addItem();  // addItem function call
    }
});
```

**call `addItem` on add button click**

```
document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener("click", addItem);
function addItem() {
    // addItem code    
}
```

**Mitigate browser inconsistencies with `javascript` libraries like jQuery**
In your code you might have noticed about getting the keycode value using `which`.

However jQuery normalises event.which depending on whether event.which, event.keyCode or event.charCode is supported by the browser:

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, been out with the cold.  Anyways I tried that and it fixed both issues, so thanks!

Comment: ...Though I'm still confused why for my issue #1 I get different POST results when adding the function directly in the HTML tag vs using javascript to add it to the DOM.

Comment: @Randy It might be the issue with browser compatibility. Check [disable form submit on enter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235672/3543808)