# Wrong value length of input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function with `onkeydown()` event and get value length of input text, when **I press `ctrl+a` / block a text (with 5 character) on it and type single character but **ouput value length of input is 4 instead 0**.

```js
function typeInput(that) {
  console.log($(that).val().length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeydown="typeInput(this)">
```

Comment: Are you supplying `that`? `onkeydown="typeInput(this)"` and it should be `$(that).val().length()`

Comment: @Satpal sorry my mistake, that is already have `.val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple things.  I really like the `this` keyword so I normally bind my events, like as follows.  Additionally, I think you want the `onkeyup` instead of `onkeydown`, because onkeydown is fired before the newest character is added to the `.val()`.

```js
function typeInput(){
   console.log($(this).val().length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="typeInput.bind(this)()">
```

Comment: This is the actual answer, the issue with the original question was the fact after he _cleared_ the input it was still outputting the length of the old text.

Comment: Exactly, why I still using `onkeydown` instead of `onkeyup`? I want prevent enter key on input, I have follow on this question [disable form submit on enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter), if I using `onkeyup` and press `enter` key, submit form still firing. I know that is different problem with my question now but it's still have relation. thanks @nfn neil

Comment: Oh, you need to target the form when preventing submit.

Comment: @nfnneil  you are very fast.+1

Comment: @AlivetoDie  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="typeInput.bind(this)()">
```

Rest code is completely fine.

Working example:-

```js
function typeInput(that) {
  console.log($(this).val().length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="typeInput.bind(this)()">
```