# Why is this not working? How can I pass the caller object to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
var submitbutton = $('#form_submit');
submitbutton.addClass('disabled');
$('#form_primer').on('keyup', validator(this));
$('#form_szek').on('keyup', validator(this));

function validator(event){
    if(isNaN(event.value)){
        $(event).css('border-color', 'red');
        submitbutton.addClass('disabled');
    }
    else{
        $(event).css('border-color', 'green');
        submitbutton.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  };
```

So, I have this javascript, and don't want to write the validator function twice. This script should disable the submit button and color the border red or green based on the input. How can I pass the form element to the function? Also, how can I disable the form submission properly? The button can't be pressed, but if the user hits enter with text inside, it will still submit it.

Comment: Avoid using `event` as a variable to refer your element in the event handler, it's dedicated for the event itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to pass a variable to the event handler, you can access element directly using `this` keyword:

```
var submitbutton = $('#form_submit');
submitbutton.addClass('disabled');
$('#form_primer').on('keyup', validator);
$('#form_szek').on('keyup', validator);

function validator() {
  if (isNaN(this.value)) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    submitbutton.addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'green');
    submitbutton.removeClass('disabled');
  }
};
```

**Note:**

Avoid using `event` as a variable to refer your element in the event handler, it's dedicated for the event itself.

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo:

```js
var submitbutton = $('#form_submit');
submitbutton.addClass('disabled');
$('#form_primer').on('keyup', validator);
$('#form_szek').on('keyup', validator);

function validator() {
  if (isNaN(this.value)) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    submitbutton.addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'green');
    submitbutton.removeClass('disabled');
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="form_submit">
<input type="text" id="form_primer">
<input type="text" id="form_szek">
```

Comment: @MyiEyeNo in fact it's, you can check it in the Demo.

Comment: Got it, its working, thanks ^^ Also, my other question: how do I stop a form from submiting on enter pressed?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that THIS was supposed to be the outside context. My bad.

Comment: @Drake you need to trgger `keyup` event on the `form` and use `e.preventDefault()` if Enter is pressed, take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `validator` should be in `function() {}` of event.

## Edit

Changed `event` var to `object`. Good point there @evolutionxbox

```js
var submitbutton = $('#form_submit');
$('#form_primer').on('keyup', function() {
  validator(this)
});
$('#form_szek').on('keyup', function() {
  validator(this)
});

function validator(object) {
  if (isNaN(object.value)) {
    $(object).css('border-color', 'red');
    submitbutton.addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(object).css('border-color', 'green');
    submitbutton.removeClass('disabled');
  }
};
```

```css
.disabled {
  border: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="form_submit">
<input type="text" id="form_primer">
<input type="text" id="form_szek">
```

Comment: The `event` variable is misleading. I know the name isn't yours, but it would be worth changing it.