# After adding input field in div using jquery form is submitted on enter

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp, jquery-chosen

I am relatively new to JavaScript but I have experience with programming. I have this code which allows the user to add multiple expenses as shown in picture. But after appending the div input field (Cost) on enter the page is submitted. and the chosen css is not working (class is not working).

Please help me i dont understand that why the page is submitted on enter key in input field.

[image: On load page is like this and if i will enter after entering the value in this input field page is working fine (means page is not submitted]

[image: After append or adding move expense the page is looks like this and we can see chosen class is also not working properly also after entering the value of cost if i will press the enter key the page is submitted.]

my code is:-

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<jsp:include page="../template.document.head.jsp" />

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#expenses").addClass('menu_item_active');

        var groupId = $("#id").val();

        if (groupId != '') {
            $("#heading").text("Edit Expense Details");
        } else {
            $("#heading").text("Add New Expense");
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#expense_id").change(function() {
            var expense_id = $("#expense_id").val();
            populateSubExpenses(expense_id);
        });
    });

    var subgroups;

    function populateSubExpenses(expense_id){
        var url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/transport/getexpensesbygroup?exp_grp_id="+expense_id;
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            subgroups = data;
            populateSubExp(data, 0);
        }, "json");
    }

    function populateSubExp(data, id){
        var selectedDeviceModel = $('#name');
        if(id != 0)
            selectedDeviceModel = $('#name_' + id);
         selectedDeviceModel.empty();
         selectedDeviceModel.append(' <option value=""> Select Expense Name</option>');
         $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             selectedDeviceModel.append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
             selectedDeviceModel.trigger("chosen:updated");
         });
    }

    var row = 1;
    function removeStops(row) {
        calTotalCost(row);
        $("#row"+row).remove();
    }

    function addExpense(){
        var htm = "<div class='row'  id='row"+row+"'>" 
                + "<div style='width:215px; height: 24px;float:left;padding-right:10px;margin-top: 0px;'>"
                + "<select name='name' id='name_" + row + "' style='height: 24px; margin-top: 10px;width:150px !important' class='chosen-select-width' tabindex='1'>"
                + "<option value='' label='Select Expense Name' />"
                + "</select>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<div style='width:55px; height: 24px;float:left;padding-right:10px;margin-top: 10px;'>"
                + "<input type='text' name='payment' id='payment_" + row + "' class='txt-field number-field' maxlength='6' style='width:50px;' onfocusout='calTotalCost(" + row + ")' onKeyDown='if(event.keyCode==13) calTotalCost(" + row + ")'/>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<div style='width:305px; height: 24px;float:left;margin-top: 10px;'>"
                + "<textarea name='remark' id='remark_" + row + "' class='txt-field' style='width:300px;'></textarea>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<div style='width:50px; height: 24px;float:left;margin-top: 10px;'>"
                + "<input type='button' value='Remove' class='btn-login' style='font-size: 10px; margin-top: 1px; margin-left: 20px;' onclick='removeStops(" + row + ");'/>"
                + "</div>"
                + "</div>";

        $("#expenseDiv").append(htm);
        populateSubExp(subgroups, row);
        row++;
    }

    function calTotalCost(row) {
        var i = 0;
        var final_payment = 0;
        for(i; i <= row ; i++){
            if(i == 0)
                payment = $('#payment').val();
            else
                payment = $('#payment' + '_' + i).val();
            if (payment != undefined)
                final_payment = parseFloat(final_payment) + parseFloat(payment);
        }
        $('#final_payment').val(final_payment);
    }

</script>

<div class="frm-block-outer" style="width:70%;">
    <div class="headinginner">
        <h3 id="heading" style="margin: 0px;"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="frm-wrapper" style="width: 980px;">
        <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/transport/addexpense" modelAttribute="expenseSubGroup" id="frmLogin" method="post" commandName="expenseSubGroup">
            <div style="float: left;">
                <fieldset class="mem-field-set">
                    <legend>Account Group Details</legend>
                    <form:input path="id" id="id" type="hidden" class="txt-field" />

                    <div class="nmem-input-pair mandatory">
                        <label>Date: <span class="req_field">*</span></label>
                        <div class="row-field">
                            <form:input path="expense.expense_date" id="expense_date" class="txt-field date-field-fy"/>
                            <form:errors path="expense.expense_date" class="field-error"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nmem-input-pair mandatory">
                        <label>Expense Group:<span class="req_field">*</span></label>
                        <div class="row-field">
                            <form:select path="expense.id" id="expense_id" style="height: 24px;width:150px !important" class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="1">
                                <form:option value="" label="Select Account Name" />
                                <form:options items="${groupName}"/>
                            </form:select>
                            <form:errors path="expense.name" class="field-error"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nmem-input-pair mandatory">
                        <label>Through:<span class="req_field">*</span></label>
                        <div class="row-field">
                            <form:select path="expense.partner_id"  style="height: 24px;width:150px !important" id="partner_id" class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="1">
                                <form:option value="" label="Select" />
                                <form:options items="${partners}"/>
                            </form:select>
                            <form:errors path="expense.partner_id" class="field-error"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <fieldset> 
                        <hr>
                        <div style="margin-left: 100px;" id="expenseDiv">

                            <div style="float: left;width: 685px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <div style="float: left; width: 200px; text-align: center;">
                                    <label>Expense</label>
                                </div>

                                <div style="float: left; width: 100px; text-align: center;">
                                    <label>Cost</label>
                                </div>

                                <div style="float: left; width: 300px; text-align: center;">
                                    <label>Description</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:215px; height: 24px;float:left;padding-right:10px;">
                                <form:select path="name"  style="height: 24px;width:150px !important" class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="1">
                                    <form:option value="" label="Select Expense Name" />
                                </form:select>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:55px; height: 24px;float:left;padding-right:10px;">
                                <form:input path="payment" id="payment" class="txt-field number-field" maxlength="6" style="width:50px;" onfocusout="calTotalCost(0)" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) calTotalCost(0)"/>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:305px; height: 24px;float:left;">
                                <form:textarea path="remark" class="txt-field" style="width:300px;"></form:textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:50px; height: 24px;float:left;">
                                <a onclick="addExpense();"><input title="Add" class="jqueryaddrow" type="button"  style="font-size: 10px; margin-top: -1px; margin-left: 20px;"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="nmem-input-pair mandatory">
                            <label>Total Payment:<span class="req_field">*</span></label>
                            <div class="row-field">
                                <form:input path="expense.final_payment" id="final_payment" class="txt-field number-field" maxlength="6" style="width:50px;"/>
                                <form:errors path="expense.final_payment" class="field-error"></form:errors>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="nmem-input-pair">
                            <label>Remark:<span class="req_field"></span></label>
                            <div class="row-field">
                                <form:textarea path="expense.remark" class="txt-field"></form:textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <div class="mem-input-pair" style="margin-left: 184px;">
                <div class="login-btn gapl-110">
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/transport/expense">
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn-grey" style="width:105px;" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="login-btn">
                    <input name="updatebtn" id="updatebtn" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn-login" style="width:105px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../template.document.tail.jsp" />
```

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: _“Please help me how can i avoid onenter submit of append div input field”_ - please do some proper research before asking here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery disable form submit on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter)

Comment: @CBroe please look into my code. I am doing some other work on enter. but it is submitted on enter.

Comment: What “other work on enter”? Please be specific, and at least say what part of the script or what specific function you are referring to.

Comment: @CBroe We can see the 2nd image i have append the div. in all the appended div's only input field(Cost)  is not working (means on enter page is submitted) and all other fields are working fine.

Comment: Submitting a form when you press enter in a text input field is the default (if there is only this one text input field in the form anyway) ... if you do not want that, you have to explicitly suppress it, using some additional JS ...

Comment: @CBroe Yes I no that the default behavior of input field but have specified the type of the field as text.

Comment: _“but have specified the type of the field as text”_ - and pressing enter in a `text` input field submits the form (if it is the only text input field) ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151910/discussion-between-ravindra-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

as per html form will trigger submit on hit of enter but if you want to prevent it with jquery you can prevent it by following code

```
 $("#frmLogin").on("submit", function(){
      return false;
 })
```

Comment: I want to know that why my form is submitted on enter. while i am calling some other function on enter key.

Comment: because enter is the default browser behaviour if you are wrapping any inputs inside form.