# Yii2 - Submit Active-form only on click over submit button, not at pressing enter key

Tags: forms, yii2, submit

I'm working in an active form and adding some fields dynamically using a `GridView`, but when I have to filter data and I press the enter key (on `GridView` to begin filtering) the form is submitted.

How to avoid "submitting" on press Enter key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Refer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter)

```
$('#formid').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```