# Avoid only form submission on Enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've one form in that having some inputs as well as textarea like below.

```
<form id="my_form" action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  Note:<br>
  <textarea id="note" name="note"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've to disable form submission on pressing Enter key. Form should be submitted only on click of submit button.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter) solution on stackoverflow, so I wrote below code.

```
$("#my_form").keypress( function( e ) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( code == 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

It's working fine but not allowing **newline to be entered in the textarea** on pressing Enter key. How do I achieve this?

Comment: So you want the form submit only if user click on Submit button correct?

Comment: Yes. Form should be submitted only on click of submit button.

Comment: do this one `<button type="button" onclick="formSubmit()">Submit</button` right js for `formSubmit` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter)

Comment: @A.Meshu - As I checked it's not possible duplicate because I have to avoid "only" form submission on Enter key press and do not have to block normal functionality of Enter key on that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your button with this button

```
<button type="button" onclick="formSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

then handler submit event with javascript like below.

```
function formSubmit() { 
    //here your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy, just change:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

To:

`<input type="button" value="Submit">`

Then handle click of button in jQuery (or pure JS).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="my_form" action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="f">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="l">
  <br>
  Note:<br>
  <textarea id="note" name="note"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>

  $("#note").keypress( function( e ) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( code == 13 ) {

      return true;
    }
  });
  $("#f").keypress( function( e ) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( code == 13 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  });
  $("#l").keypress( function( e ) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( code == 13 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Give `id`s to first name and last name input. Disable keypress on them.

Comment: This is extremely inflexible.   Every time you add a new input you have to add code to determine how to handle the enter?  Better handled with a `data-` attribute if you want this sort of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not()` Selector for input.

```
$("#my_form:not(input:text)").keypress( function( e ) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ( code == 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Would `#my_form` ever be an `input:text`?  As in your code would only work with this: `<form><input type='text' id='my_form'/></form>`?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the $("#my_form") to $("#my_form **input:text**").

So code will looks like,

```
$("#my_form input:text").keypress( function( e ) {
    //Do stuff here
});
```