# Tab through elements using Enter key including select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using following code to tab through form elements using enter key.  Problem is that this code skip select2 elements.

```
        $('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function(e) {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
                var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next;
                focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':not([disabled]):not([tabindex="-1"]):visible');
                next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
                if (next.length) {
                    next.focus();
                } else {
                    //form.submit();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can u create JSFiddle ?

Comment: What select2 version are you using for testing?

Comment: select2 will not keep `<select>` tag it trasforms the html to list item using `<li>` tag, but the enter key is assumed as selection of an element in select2, when I tested, after a normal `<input>` tag the cursor focus happens to the next select2 element, from there it is not jumping to next, there is already a keypress handled in select2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `keydown` to `keyup`

```
  $('body').on('keyup', 'input, select', function(e)
```

Reason is `keydown` is already handled in `select2` library for choosing an item

Comment: OP's issue is *also* that `$("select:visible")` will bypass the select2's hidden select - so the focus doesn't go *into* select2 (rather than out of)

Comment: no, the visible is applied to all tags using  `form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea')` so if there is a `input` it will be trapped, I test the code in jsfiddle is was working

Comment: When I changed keydown to keyup the select2 does get focus, but now on pressing enter on an input the form gets submitted.

Comment: yes, that should be a different question, you need to disable it -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235622/jquery-disable-form-submit-on-enter

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I will mark this as answer and submit a new question.