# Button fires event after textbox was entered

Tags: html, button, input, postback

I have a htmlpage with three inputfields and a button. It looks like this:

i don't think it will help, but anyhow:

```
  <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Start:</td>
            <td><input ID="txtStart" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eind:</td>
            <td><input ID="txtEind" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" onclick="javascript:alert('test');"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Station:</td>
            <td><input ID="txtStation" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If i enter text in textbox 3 and i press enter,  then button 1 fires an event(javascript:alert("this is a test");). How can i disable this? The button should only fire an event when i click it. It should not be related to textbox 3...

I think it has something to with postback or something? Or maybe a defaultbutton?

Any help welcome :)

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information.  Add the HTML and JavaScript for the part of the page with your form elements and what events you're triggering.  A good way to have a working example for us to respond to is to use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i've added the code i'm using...

Answer (score 0):

Your button may be marked as type="submit". If this doesn't solve can you post some HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in an input element within a `<form>` (in most browsers) triggers the `submit` action for that form.

The only way to avoid this is a little javascript intervention; Either add a check on the `submit` action of the form to test that all fields have been populated or catch the `keypress` event of the input element and discard any <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key presses.

*See Also: [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form) .*

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the textbox 3 and the button within the same `<form>` tag, the button will automatically be assigned to textbox 3 as well, thus Enter activates the submit button.

If you want to get rid of this, put it into another form (as you said textbox 3 isn't related to the button right?).

Comment: can i place two form-elements on my page?

Answer (score 0):

if i use an asp:net button i can give that a property `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`, that solved my problem! But anyhow, thank you!