# Javascript: enter in input element with strange behaviour on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, input

I have a html form with a select, button and an input element.

```
<form action="">
    <button>innocent button</button>
    <select multiple name="multiple">
    <option selected value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<input style="width:300px" type="text" value="press here enter and look at the multiple select" name="" />
</form>
```

and some jquery javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('hi');


            var $button = $('button');

            $button.on('click',function(e){

                $('select option').first().attr('selected',false);
                e.preventDefault();

            });
```

Demo: try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Rjdh/

On Chrome everything is okay.
But on Firefox:
If you press ENTER in the input field, the select element loses it's selected.

What is wrong with Firefox?

Comment: The form is being submitted, you are seeing a page refresh. The same thing will also happen in other browsers such as Safari.

Comment: +1 for _innocent button_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I fixed it by adding the attribute type with value button

http://jsfiddle.net/3Rjdh/2/

Comment: Maybe I am missing your objective here, but your form is still being submitted (FF15/Win)

Comment: In the first fiddle, the <select> element is changing it's value after you press enter in the input element and before the form submits.

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter on the input, you are effectively firing the click event of the button, trying putting a conole.log in there and you'd see it fire

You can stop the submission by [doing something this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form)

```
  function stopSubmit(e){
      e = e || event;
      return (e.keyCode || event.which || event.charCode || 0) !== 13;
   }
```

Then in your form add the event for keypress

```
    <form onkeypress="return stopSubmit(event)">
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rjdh/1/)

Comment: and how can I prevent firing the click event on the button?

Comment: @christianhaller Maybe I am missing your objective here, but your form is still being submitted (FF15/Win)