# how prevent submit on press enter in twitter bootstrap typeahead plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, form-submit, preventdefault

I have a input text and I apply it typeahead plugin for suggesting items, but when I press enter key on input text it submit form.

How can I prevent form submit using twitter bootstrap typeahead plugin?

Answer (score 24):

You can target that specific input by adding an ID to it and simply removing the keydown event for enter like so:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form input').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You may not want the `return false`. @See http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Maybe @paganotti wants to press enter key to submit form on others input and ignore the tag input only.

Answer (score 3):

The first answer didn't worked for me, maybe because of updating the typeahead plugin, but I did passed the problem by using the 'alternative' input created by typehead:

```
$(".twitter-typeahead > input").focus(function(){
    //disable btn when focusing the input
    $("#my_submit_button").prop('disabled', true);
}).blur(function(){
    //enable btn when bluring the input
    $("#my_submit_button").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#options), you can set the option `confirmKeys` to something else than return (13) :

```
$('input').tagsinput({
   confirmKeys: [188, 32, 39],
});
```

However, a smarter way to go about this is to [prevent sending the form on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form).

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem in my project using CodeIgniter and bootstrap
here i found the solution and it works.

Just add `onsubmit="return false;"` in the form, like this:

```
<form id="frmcrud" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: This was what I needed.  Further I wanted clicking the search icon or pressing enter to trigger the search (using documented `trigger('input.typeahead')` ) without a form submission (at least for now) so extended onsubmit to trigger the search event: `onsubmit="console.log('trigger manual search of .js-typeahead-frmcrud'); $('.js-typeahead-frmcrud').trigger('input.typeahead'); return false;"`

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to approach this is not to use a submit input. Use a button input instead and add some js to submit the form when it's clicked.

```
$('#my_submit_button').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').keydown(function( event ) {
 if ( event.which == 13 ) {
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).focus();
    return false;
 }
})
```