# bootstrap-tagsinput form submited on press enter key

Tags: forms, input, bootstrap-tags-input

in `bootstrap-tagsinput` on press enter key for next tag form is submitted!
what is the solution?

```
$("#inputID").tagsinput();
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue ... have you found any solution.

Comment: which backend framework you use ? share sample code ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how prevent submit on press enter in twitter bootstrap typeahead plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551668/how-prevent-submit-on-press-enter-in-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-plugin)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you'll want to map 'Enter' to your `tagsinput`'s `confirmkeys` option, then you'll need to call `preventDefault()` on your enter key to prevent the form from being submitted. In my solution, it only prevents submission by enter key while the user is focused in the tags input field.

To add a bit of redundancy, I also re-map the enter key to a comma in the input field, just to be sure.

```
  $('#tags-input').tagsinput({
    confirmKeys: [13, 188]
  });

  $('#tags-input input').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
      e.keyCode = 188;
      e.preventDefault();
    };
  });
```

Just also an FYI, Enter key is mapped as 13, and comma is 188 in JS.

Comment: This has been really helpful. I'd like to add an update. I think comma keycode changed to 44 now.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').keydown(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to **tagsinput.js**

Find line:

```
self.$container.on('keypress', 'input', $.proxy(function(event) {
```

Before the end of this function add following:

```
if (event.which == 13) {
    return false; // dont submit form !!
}
```

Comment: If the source is piece of sh*, I'd like to fix it. Have a beautiful day Jeff.

Comment: Agreed 100%. The usual process is suggesting a fix and submit the fix with a PR though instead of editing the source directly.

Answer (score 1):

Enter key is register for  postback form . that's why a case has been happened that when you hit 'enter' key it trigger the 'postback' event so the form goes to submitted  .
solution :
on page load reserve the enter key for tag input :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { onkeydown = "return event.keyCode!=13" }))
```

if using  asp.net mvc framework this is a simple example .

Comment: The prevents the item from been added to the input in the first place

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput input[type=text]').on('keydown', function (e) {
   if ( event.which == 13 ) {
           $(this).blur();
           $(this).focus();
           return false;
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty option is set to true by default, but when set to false calls .preventDefault on the tag delimeter keydown event. Set it to false.

This solution also fixes the issue of a "carried comma".

```
cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty: false,

// If the field is empty, let the event triggered fire as usual
if (self.options.cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty === false) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```