# Disable enter submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a textfield inside and I am trying to disable the default behavior when the browser submits the whole form if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the textfield is selected.

```
$('#recaptcha_response_field').keydown(function(event) { if (event.keyCode == 13) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     alert("You Press ENTER key");
     return false;
   } 
});
```

Currently am getting "You Press ENTER key" and the default behavior isn't overridden.

Comment: Don't use keydown event of input, use submit event of form.

Comment: You should also handle `keyup` event.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form  Pls ask your question to google before submitting it here. this would have provided you with the original question that has already been answered at length.

Comment: `preventDefault` is absolutely enough. Neither do you need to stop propagation, nor return false.

Comment: See this post http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx

Comment: @roasted but how could we know in onsubmit event that this form is submitted using enter key.

Comment: @roasted can you give a reason for your response? yes you can of course use the submit handler but why would you instead of keydown/keyup on the enter key? either would work here and you make it see as though you're saying keydown will NOT work.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe  I'm really not sure it is cross browser to stop submitting form from a keydown event on an input element. Maybe i'm wrong but...

Comment: @iAmClownShoe  I just tested and seems you cannot, so you need to use submit handler (tested in chrome)

Comment: Ok, i tested on keyup doesn't work but works on keydown. Keyup is fired after submit, that's why.

Comment: yes. keyup will of course fire afterwards so keydown is the one you must use.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("keypress", 'form', function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will prevent the form submit on `keypress`

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Avvk/)

Comment: keyup fires after the submit and therefore, you cannot disable default behavior since it has already happened.

Comment: Also stops textareas from pressing enter for new lines \n

Comment: `keydown` fires first so it is safest to use.

Answer (score 13):

I found this and it works for me.

```
<input type="text" name="somename" id="someid" value="" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13">
```

Answer (score 9):

To prevent the script from blocking the enter key on other elements such as on a textarea. Change the target from "form" to "input".

```js
$(document).on("keypress", "input", function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, man, only one what truly helped for my case

Answer (score 3):

If none of the above solution is working for you , and you are using javascript anyway , why don't you use button type as 'button' `<input type='button'>` and submit it using javascript

```
$('#form_id').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use this script to prevent enter on entire from.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("keypress", 'form', function (e) {
            if (e.target.className.indexOf("allowEnter") == -1) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

you put the classname to which control need to use enter

Comment: probably will not work on Mac as Mac has different keycodes