# How to prevent enter key submit in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Simple example:

```
 <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path  do |f|%>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title%><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :title%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :text%><br/>
        <%= f.text_area :text%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit%>
    </p>
<%end%>
```

I think this is a Rails default event handling. In here, if the user presses the enter key, it submits the `params`.

But in my case, I have to use the enter key for another event.

I have to search `users` with another input field by pressing the enter key.

But if I use `form_for` it submits the form. :(

How can I prevent submitting with the enter key in `rails`?

Do I have to use plain html tags? Like `<form> tag` and `<submit> button`?

Any good solutions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Enter key submit is not a rails problem, it's an HTML / JS problem

Rails is backend (lives on the server); HTML / JS are client-side (live in browser) - they determine what functionality is enabled / disabled

I would get around your problem like this:

```
$('form').on('keypress', e => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

And if you're using Turbolinks:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {
    $('form').on('keypress', e => {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Good reference: [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form)

Comment: This isn't working for me. Have also tried putting the script directly in my form partial. Should $("form") be something different if I'm using `form_tag`?

Comment: The `form` is the HTML element selector - are you using `Turbolinks` at all?

Comment: If it's not working, the cause may well be Turbolinks. See my edit for a Turbolinks solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Rails specific question it's since it's a native behaviour of all browsers. If you have a button submit in your form (and you should :) ) then every browser will submit the form after hitting enter. *I haven't checked, but even without a clear submit button it should do it]
The accepted answer is correct, but since there is a thread that gives a more complex example I would go through it too:

[Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter)

Answer (score 0):

```
        $( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

          document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) { 
              if (13 == e.keyCode) { 
                  event.preventDefault(); 
                  return false;
              } 
          });
        });
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.