# why does pressing enter inside a text box click the first button and submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Open the javascript console, put your cursor in the text box, and press enter. Why is the function "baz" called? How should it be suppressed?

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}
function bar() {
  console.log('bar');
}
function baz() {
  console.log('baz');
}
function blee() {
  console.log('blee');
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="foo()" action="javascript:blee()">
 <input type="text" />
 <button onclick="baz()">baz</button>
 <button onclick="bar()">bar</button>
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's the question? Why it is like this (most likely because the spec says so) or how to prevent it? The latter is a duplicate of [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/585396/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser thinks the button that follows the input is a submit button. If you were to switch the baz button with the bar button, it would call the bar() function.

You can fix this by adding 'type="button"' to both of your buttons.