# form submits on enter in any of its elements like text field, checkbox ,drop down in chrome and Firefox , need a generic fix ?

Tags: javascript

form closed on enter in any of its elements like text field, checkbox ,drop down in chrome and Firefox , need a generic fix ? 
In internet explorer it is not reproducible but chrome and Firefox submits the form on enter in any of its elements ,

note-: elements in which there is no need of enter , issue is happening there ,like text field doesn't need enter it closes it , checkbox doesn't needed it ,it also closes it .

Comment: enter for submit is what normally happens with forms. So cancel the form submission or remove the submit button.

Comment: how would we remove the submit button , it should be needed for submit the form .

Comment: @epascarello is there any alternative for this issue except restrict enter key on page ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form)

Comment: i want to prevent it implicitly not by js