# Postback in older VB .Net Application and Javascript event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an old VB.Net application that I need to modify some functionalities, I added:

```
<input type="text" id="hiddenAccountNumber" class="js-card" placeholder="Test" onkeypress="readKeyPress()"/>
```

The function `readKeyPress` has some logic to read the data in the input once you do Enter with the keyboard... My problem is that everytime a hit Enter on the keyboard the whole page do a PostBack and my javascript code is never executed... I need my javascript code execute only. Any idea please?

I don't see any Form tag actually this is a piece of the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div class="AccountSummary" style="float:right;">
         <uc:AccountSummary id="ucAccountSummary" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateTransactionControls" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
```

But it has a few UC and has this triggers:

```
<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucGeneralPaymentPosting" 
                EventName="SetupPaymentForm" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucGeneralPaymentPosting" 
                EventName="ClearPaymentForm" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucDentalFirstFinancing" 
                EventName="InvalidDentalFirstSSN" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReviewPayment" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnBackToCollectData" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucCareCredit" 
                EventName="ShowAuthorizationForm" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmitPayment" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelete" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelete" EventName="Click" />
            <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ucThirdPartyLenderAccountInformation" EventName="CheckEmailSelection" />--%>
        </Triggers>
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  Specifically if this is within a form tag?

Comment: I added some piece of code @BrianK.Burge but I don't see any form tag, and I verified all the buttons in the page has useSubmitBehavior = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to return false to prevent Postback:

`onkeypress="readKeyPress(); return false;"`

Or at the end of your `readKeyPress()` function.

Using an `UpdatePanel` and `ScriptManager` from `Ajax Control Toolkit` would be another option.

**EDIT:**

Then you'll have to call the `preventDefault()` method:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Here's an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19379604/1821637

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoTrejo I did this: `<input type="text" id="hiddenAccountNumber" class="js-card" placeholder="Test" onkeypress="readKeyPress(); return false;"/>` but it still sending a postback

Comment: Thanks Santiago I found quite a helpful your links, I think I found the solution.