# Extjs 4 event stop propagation not working

Tags: javascript, extjs4, event-propagation

I am using Extjs 4 and overriding a `Ext.util.Observable` as the name `Ext.tree.Search`. In the extended class I have implemented event listener `onTriggerSearch` so when the user types some words in input and presses enter key, this function is get called and do some search job. The search plugin has a view like the image below:

[image: search plugin view screenshot]

If the user submit the search by pressing magnifier icon, everything goes right but if press enter key, after doing the search, the page gets refreshed. How should I catch this event (key press event) completely and stop propagating. The thing I have tested by now is lines below:

```
, onTriggerSearch: function (a, event, c) {
        // stop event propagation
        if (event.browserEvent.stopPropagation)
            event.browserEvent.stopPropagation();
        if (event.browserEvent.cancelBubble != null)
            event.browserEvent.cancelBubble = true;
//        event.browserEvent.bubbles = false;
//        event.browserEvent.cancelBubble = true;
//        event.browserEvent.stopPropagation();
        // ======================
        ... some other jobs
        return false; // to stop propagation
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some weeks I had trouble with this issue and by now I have discovered that the problem is with the form containing this input. I have prevented form to submit using these answers:

[How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form)

Done.